# Substring match on a field in json index

Tags: cloudant, couchdb-mango

I want to be able to match a substring using a JSON index, but I can't seem to work out how to do it.

I have a record in the data with a `data.name` property of `A SIGN DESIGN PTY. LTD.`. My index is defined as follows:

```
db.index({
  name: 'subbies_text',
  type: 'json',
  index: {
    fields: ['data.name']
  },
})
```

Is there a selector that I can use that will perform a substring match so that I can search for "sign" or "sign design" and have "A SIGN DESIGN PTY. LTD." included in the search results?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with "$regex". Suppose you have succeeded created a json index named "subbies_text", next is the example of the query:

```
{"selector": { "_id": { "$gt": 0 }, "subbies_text":{"$regex":"SIGN" } }, "fields": [ "_id", "_rev", "name" ]}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to manipulate the indexed values with this approach?  

How can I uppercase values to provide case insensitivity?

How can I remove spaces from formatted numbers so they match any formatting in the query string?

It feels to me that querying a design doc directly is a better solution.